# Implicit Index for table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am learning Postgresql and db in general. I have a simple query like this and I want to understand what it does

```
CREATE TABLE adempiere.c_mom(
c_mom_id NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
isactive character(1) DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar NOT NULL,
start_date date NOT NULL,
start_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
end_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT c_mom_pkey PRIMARY KEY (c_mom_id)
);
```

So after I execute this I got

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "c_mom_pkey" for table "c_mom"
```

1. Now I know that my PK `is c_mom_id`, but what is the purpose of creating an implicit index it under name `c_mom_key`?
2. What does `DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar`, or in general what does `::` in psql do?

Thank you

Comment: not related to your question but `isactive character(1) DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar NOT NULL,` means using one UTF-8 encoded character to stroe a 0/1 single bit value (so several bytes for one bit), please use the boolean data type to store booleans.

Comment: BTW you do not need both `start_date` and `start_time`. `timestamp` includes both date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::` notation is a PostgreSQL-specific [type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) notation, in this case to type `bpchar` (blank-padded char).

An index is created to back primary keys to make them efficient. If there wasn't an index to back it, each insert statement would have to scan the whole table just to figure out if that insertion would create a duplicate key or not. Using an index speeds that up (dramatically if the table is large).

This is not PostgreSQL specific. A lot of relational databases will create unique indexes to back primary keys.